# Input & output array of strings that are dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

Basically, using dynamic allocation, I want to input 5 names and then print them out.

Code:

```
int main()
{
    char* names = new char[5];
    string name;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        gets(name);
        names[i] = name;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
    {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }

    delete [] names;
    return 0;
}
```

It says I can't convert string to char*.

The strings I want to input have spaces, ex: Bob Smith.

Comment: Just so we make sure you're not making things harder on yourself when you don't need to: is there any reason you're not just using an array of `string`? Or a `vector` of `string`?

Comment: I've tried that but it says `error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* gets(char*)` at `gets(name)`

Comment: What are you even using `gets`? It's been removed from the C standard because it's dangerous.

Comment: `std::gets` expects a `char *` ( a buffer it can jam input into ). It's a backwards-compatible relic from C. The C++ equivalent would be to use `std::getline(std::cin, string_array[i]);` or something that looks kind of like that.

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, string_array[i])` works, thanks.

Comment: @Peter Indeed - my mistake (I was playing around with OP's code and messed it up).

Comment: @JohnFilleau I guess that's .‎

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++ equivalent of what you're trying to do. Please let us know if this doesn't solve your issue (for example, a class where the professor thinks C++ is just C with extra stuff).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

constexpr unsigned int NUM_NAMES = 5;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_NAMES; ++i)
    {
        std::string name;
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
        names.push_back(name);
    }

    for (const auto & name : names)
    {
        std::cout << name << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tested this and ran with the following I/O:

```
john smith
BOB VILLA
homer SiMpSoN
Spongebob Squarepants (lives in a pineapple etc etc)
FooBar McBizBaz
john smith
BOB VILLA
homer SiMpSoN
Spongebob Squarepants (lives in a pineapple etc etc)
FooBar McBizBaz
```